# Cordova build for iOS - No profile found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am confronted with a cordova builds on MacOS. The builds work fine for Android, but building iOS is really painful. Here is what happens:

```
>cordova build ios --device --debug --buildConfig ./build.json
.....
Check dependencies
No profile matching '******' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching '******'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
```

This is a fresh install of latest versions of everything (node, cordova, cordova-ios, XCode, etc). I have everything set in terms of developer id, team, certificates and provisioning profiles. All those artifacts are valid and I know for sure because I am moving this build from Intel XDK into my local Mac computer. Here is my build.json:

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "provisioningProfile": "******",
            "developmentTeam": "******",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "provisioningProfile": "******",
            "developmentTeam": "*******",
            "packageType": "app-store"
        }
    }
}
```

I can see all my provisioning profiles in XCode account preferences. I also see them in `/Users/me/Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles` folder. I've opened XCode project and adjusted the code signing for project and target in Build Settings and General tabs. The provisioning profiles are there, the team ID is there.

All I need now is to make cordova command line work.

So, how can I make cordova and XCode to cooperate? Where does it look for those profiles and why can't it find them? What gives?

Comment: I've managed to run the cordova generated project it in XCode with emulator, it works OK. But I am unable to produce ipa files because of these signing issues.

Comment: I have also managed to use cordova generated project in XCode to export the product into ipa and run it on the iPhone. But I am totally stuck with cordova command line to generate ipa files without any user interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've almost given up on this, but then..  magic happened.
Everything have fixed itself by upgrading Cordova to 7.0.1, MacOS to 10.12.5 and XCode to 8.3.2.
Frankly, I have no idea what was broken, the primary suspect is XCode - the most scary development environment in the universe.

Comment: Cordova 7.0.1, OS X 10.12.5, Xcode 8.3.3, same problem, but still having the same issue...

Comment: I feel your pain.., not idea why it started to work for me all of a sadden. I renewed provisioning profiles, may be this was also a factor.

Comment: I use a free "Personal team" provision profile, may be that's the problem ?

Comment: I am not sure it is the same problem. I did have valid profiles and I could be able to build manually (running XCode) using the project created by cordova. My problem was that this didn't work from the command line and I had to open this nasty XCode to build the release all the time. Try to open the generated project in XCode and see if you can build it manually. If you can then your profile is OK, otherwise the problem is in the profile.

Comment: I can build manually without any problem. I can launch the app fine on my phone. The only thing I can't do is run the command :( Hence I can't use live reload and console logs :(

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem too and spent days trying to build until I finally figured it out. For some reason the build fails if my iPhone is plugged into the Mac, but if I unplug it, it builds perfectly fine. Then I open Xcode, plug in the phone, and run it with no problems. I have no explanation for why this happens but I haven't seen the error since. Hopefully this helps for anyone struggling with this issue.

Comment: can confirm that this issue still persists in 2019 for Xcode 10.2.1

Comment: Same here, unplugged the iPhone, build success. Xcode 12.1

Comment: can confirm that this issues still persists in the latest version Cordova 10.0.0 and Xcode 12.5. We spent 5 hrs. to find out to unplug the phone to get Cordova to compile