# Cannot deploy to device using Ionic cli (but succeed with Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, deployment

I followed all the steps mentioned in the [Ionic deployment documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/) and successfully deployed my Ionic app to my iPhone using Xcode's  "play" button, using the free "Personal team" provisioning profile. However, I cannot deploy from the command line; running `ionic cordova run iOS --device` fails and outputs:

```
=== BUILD TARGET MyApp OF PROJECT MyApp WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
No profiles for 'eu.empain.apps' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching
'eu.empain.apps'.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'
```

In Xcode, the team is set correctly in "Build settings > Signing", and the provisioning profile exists in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`.

Not being able to launch through the command line prevents me from using live reload and console logs with `-c` and `-l` options. Hence, I cannot debug errors that occur on app launch.

I'm using:

- Cordova 7.0.1
- OS X 10.12.5
- Xcode 8.3.3
- Ionic 3.4.0

I found a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022191/cordova-build-for-ios-no-profile-found), but the solution does not apply to me since all my versions are equal or greater to those mentioned in that thread.